# $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(f\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}\right)-f\left(n^{2}\right)\right)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Prove that for each function that maintains $0\le f'(x) \le \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x>0$ the limit is
$$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(f\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}\right)-f\left(n^{2}\right)\right)=0$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the interval $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$. It's easy to see that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ and is differentiable on $ (n^2,(n+1)^2)$.Use Lagrange's mean value theorem, we get
\begin{equation}
f((n+1)^2)-f(n^2)=f'(\xi)[(n+1)^2-n^2]=f'(\xi)(2n+1),\xi\in(n^2,(n+1)^2).
\end{equation}
Then we have
\begin{equation}
0\leq f'(\xi)(2n+1)\leq\frac{2n+1}{n^2}\to 0,
\end{equation}
as $n\to \infty$.